# Windows Xampp fatal error when running aws sdk

Tags: php, xampp, aws-sdk

My site is on `c:/xampp/htdocs/dev.com/`

I placed .aws inside it. I made a vhost also to specify its document root. Not sure where to place the .aws folder for credentials. I tried placing it on htdocs also but still have the error.

```
NameVirtualHost dev.loc:80
<VirtualHost dev.loc:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dev.com/" 
    ServerName dev.loc
</VirtualHost
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Exception\CredentialsException' with
>       message 'Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials'

How can I solve this?